# Program for a plot in MATLAB

Tags: matlab, plot, graph

I have seen a plot in one page. I wanted to recreate a similar plot I searched for the code but could not find the code for the plot. Attaching the plot with this of which I wanted to generate in MATLAB 
[image]

Comment: Is it the code for plotting or the equation for generating the blue line you want. The latter may not be appropriate for SO.

Comment: I was looking to generate the blue line

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As an example, here's a plot for a dampened sine curve:

```
A=10;
f=1000;
n=5;
T=1/f;
t=[0:T/100:n*T];
s=A*exp(-t*1000).*sin(2*pi*f*t);

% Here is the bit you'd be interested in:
plot(t,s,'b-','lineWidth',2) %'b-' is blue line.
xlabel('time (s)')
ylabel('amplitude (v)')
set(gca,'linewidth',2)
grid on
ax = gca;
ax.XGrid = 'off';
ax.YGrid = 'on';
set(ax,'GridLineStyle','--')
```

[image]

Change the formula or data to achieve desired plot shape.

Comment: Thank you for the code. I will modify that for the desired one

Comment: No problem.  Added the dashed lines also...